# Невозможно прочитать свойство в консоли браузера

Tags: javascript, html

Я только учусь верстать сайты и иногда сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, что при попытке добавить к элементу функцию(не только функцию, имеется ввиду вообще работа с JS), у меня в консоли браузера(обычно Chrome) появляется ошибка "Невозможно прочитать свойство", вот к примеру:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь остальной код [в гитхабе](https://github.com/nosferatu-id/featS.git) **ветка body-wr**
  *P.S. Я немного туповат*

Comment: Подключите скрипт в конец `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как браузер обрабатывает html-страницу строго сверху вниз, при вставке скрипта вам нужно быть уверенным что элементы к которым вы обращаетесь будут доступны к моменту выполнения скрипта.

Есть два способа:

1. Размещать теги script, работающие с dom-деревом (*читай: элементами*) в самом низу страницы, а именно перед `</body>`
2. Размещать можно в любом месте,  но код, работающий с элементами вызывать только при наступлении событий `DOMContentLoaded` или `load`, например:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       // Ваш код
   });
   ```

Вообще универсальный способ расположения ресурсов на странице, это когда стили вверху, в `head`, а js-код внизу.

Причин несколько:

1. Стили загружаются до отображения страницы и страница будет сразу отображаться с учетом стилей. Что будет в обратном случае, вы поймёте просто отключив стили на странице
2. JavaScript-код должен загрузиться и выполниться, это может вызвать дополнительную задержку.
3. Ваш случай: когда элемента ещё нет, а код его ищет.

Вот [замечательный сайт](https://learn.javascript.ru/first-steps) про javascript, «пройдите» его и сэкономите себе кучу времени

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, ваш скрипт помещён в `head` и срабатывает ещё до того, как `body` становится частью DOM — поэтому элемент не находится, вместо него возвращается `null`, у которого нет упомянутого свойства.

Возможны несколько выходов: обернуть код в функцию и назначить её исполнение на событие `onload` вашего `body`; или вставить элемент `script` в конец `body`; или назначить обработчик `onclick` в коде самого элемента `div`.